# Pandas dataframe to 1-d array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with lots of columns.

I first choose only one column from the dataframe by
`r_i = df.iloc[:, i: i + 1]`

Then I want to turn this `r_i` into array simply by 
`np.array(r_i)`.

the result I want is like:
`array([-1, -2, -3])`. In other words, it should be array of one list.

However, it gives me array of one list which consists of sublists:
`array([[-1], [-2], [-3]])`.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a good answer but my question is, why are you trying to do this? You can run any `Numpy` function along any axis in `Pandas` using the `apply` method already so subsetting and putting the output into a `numpy` array seems wasteful.

Answer (score 6):

```
df.values.flatten()
```

Here, df is your DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

So, given:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[5,6,7,8], 'c':[9,10,11,12]})
>>> i = 1
>>> df
   a  b   c
0  1  5   9
1  2  6  10
2  3  7  11
3  4  8  12
>>> df.iloc[:, i: i + 1]
   b
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 1])
array([[5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8]])
```

You could use the `.squeeze` method, which removes a single dimension from your array:

```
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 1]).squeeze()
array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Although I'd probably just use:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, i: i + 1].values.squeeze()
array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Or alternatively, you could always use `.reshape`, which should be your first instinct when you want to *reshape* an array:

```
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 1]).reshape(-1)
array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Note, these will behave differently if you accidentally take an extra column, so:

```
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 2])
array([[ 5,  9],
       [ 6, 10],
       [ 7, 11],
       [ 8, 12]])
```

With reshape:

```
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 2]).reshape(-1)
array([ 5,  9,  6, 10,  7, 11,  8, 12])
```

With squeeze:

```
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 2]).squeeze()
array([[ 5,  9],
       [ 6, 10],
       [ 7, 11],
       [ 8, 12]])
```

Ideally, you'd probably just want that to fail, so if you want to program defensively, use `reshape` with explicit parameters instead of `-1`:

```
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 1]).reshape((df.shape[0],))
array([5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> np.array(df.iloc[:, i: i + 2]).reshape((df.shape[0],))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (4,)
>>>
```

#### However

You could avoid this by not doing an unecessary slice, so:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, i: i + 1]
   b
0  5
1  6
2  7
3  8
>>> df.iloc[:, i + 1]
0     9
1    10
2    11
3    12
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

The latter gives you a *series*, which is already one-dimensional, so you could just use:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, i + 1].values
array([ 9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Comment: @jpp nah, it will be 2-dimensional, I thought that too at first, but it makes sense since a slice like that will create a data-frame, not a series. You'd need `df.iloc[:, i+1].values`